# Push into an array from foreach and make it available outside foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I stuck by looping through an array that receive values from a promise and push values into a new array which is available outside the foreach.

What i have:

```
   app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {
      uploadPics(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({UploadResult: err.message}));
            console.log(err.message + ' ' +'Redirect /home');
        } else if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({UploadResult: 'Success'}));
            var filesarray = req.files;
            var picinfos = [];

            filesarray.forEach(function(file){
                GetFileMetaInfo.filemetainfo(file.path).then(function (metadata){
                    //Stuck here! Can push values into an array (picinfos) but only available in the foreach. not outside..
                })
            })
            //I need picinfos array here....
        }   
    }) 
})
```

How i receive my metadata:

```
var exif = require('exif-parser');
var fs = require('fs');


exports.filemetainfo = function (filepath) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var file = filepath;
        var buffer = fs.readFileSync(file);
        var parser = exif.create(buffer);
        var result = parser.parse();
        resolve (result);
     }).then(function (metadata){
         if (metadata.tags.CreateDate !== undefined){
                date = new Date (metadata.tags.CreateDate*1000);
                datevalues = [
                    date.getFullYear(),
                    date.getMonth()+1,
                    date.getDate(),
                    date.getHours(),
                    date.getMinutes(),
                    date.getSeconds(),
                 ];
                 CreateDate = date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getDate();
                 CreateTime = date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes()+':'+date.getSeconds();
                 console.log("CrDate:" +CreateDate, "CrTime:" +CreateTime );
                } else {
                        console.log("No Metadata Creation Infos found in " +filepath);
                        CreateDate = "";
                        CretaeTime = "";
                }

                if (metadata.tags.GPSLatitude !== undefined){
                    GPSLat = metadata.tags.GPSLatitude;
                    GPSLon = metadata.tags.GPSLongitude;
                    console.log("GPSLat:" + GPSLat , "GPSLon:" +GPSLon); 
                }
                else {
                    console.log("No Metadata GPS Infos found in " +filepath)
                    GPSLat = "";
                    GPSLon = "";
               }
                return MetaData = {
                    GPSLat: GPSLat ,
                    GPSLon: GPSLon,
                    CreateDate: CreateDate,
                    CreateTime: CreateTime,
                    }   
        })
}
```

May i ask someone to give a hand. How can i make my array available outside the foreach. thank you very much!

Comment: What's your node version? (I want to see if you could use arrow functions)

Comment: I use Node.JS v10.14.2

Comment: Then Dinesh answer might be useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting empty array at the end of `forEach` is because, `GetFileMetaInfo.filemetainfo()` returns a promise and `forEach` won't wait for async actions.

You could use `async/await` with `for...of` loop to get your desired result.

```
app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {
  uploadPics(req, res, async function (err) { // note async here
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({UploadResult: err.message}));
        console.log(err.message + ' ' +'Redirect /home');
    } else if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({UploadResult: 'Success'}));
        var filesarray = req.files;
        var picinfos = [];

        for(let file of filesarray) {
          const metadata = await GetFileMetaInfo.filemetainfo(file.path);
          // push metadata into your array here
          picinfos.push(metadata);
        }

        // You will have picinfos here
    }   
  })
})
```

Comment: @Dinesh: i receive wait is only available in async function when i follow your code.

Comment: You have to convert your express handler into an async function. Look at the first line I have added a comment.

Comment: @Mansour: i never need async functions before. whats your approach?

Comment: `async` functions let you await promises in your code without having to write `then` blocks. It's a syntactic sugar to deal with promises.

Comment: @DineshPandiyan: just copied your code -> await is only valid in async function....

Comment: Ah, async should be on `uploadPics` function. I have edited my answer. Now it should work.

Comment: Ok, thats it, thanks. Need to fully understand from here about async in detail. As i said, its solved and helped me a lot. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is already [answered by Dinesh Pandiyan](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53815426/revisions) there are still some adjustments that can be made. The following code in his answer runs sequential, meaning that every async request is made after the previously returned result is resolved.

```
for(let file of filesarray) {
  const metadata = await GetFileMetaInfo.filemetainfo(file.path);
  //                 ^- pauses the execution of the current running code
  // push metadata into your array here
  picinfos.push(metadata);
}
```

```
async call #1 ╌╌await╌╌> async call #2 ╌╌await╌╌> async call #3 ╌╌await╌╌> result
```

You could make the code concurrent by first executing all async statements and then wait until all results are resolved. This can be done by simply changing the following:

```
// execute all the async functions first, reducing the wait time

for(let file of filesarray) {
  const metadata = GetFileMetaInfo.filemetainfo(file.path);
  //                 ^- remove the await
  // push metadata into your array here
  picinfos.push(metadata);
}

// wait for all results to be resolved
picinfos = await Promise.all(picinfos);
//           ^- instead await here
```

```
async call #1 ╌╌┐
async call #2 ╌╌┼╌╌await all╌╌> result
async call #3 ╌╌┘
```

The above could be further simplified by simply using an [*Array.map()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with the already shown [*Promise.all()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
var filesarray = req.files;
var picinfos = await Promise.all(filesarray.map(file => {
  return GetFileMetaInfo.filemetainfo(file.path);
}));

// picinfos should be present
```

Or if you want to avoid working with async/await:

```
var filesarray = req.files;

Promise.all(filesarray.map(file => {
  return GetFileMetaInfo.filemetainfo(file.path); 
})).then(picinfos => {
  // picinfos should be present
});
```